# Why RadioButtorFor Validation Message doesnt appear?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

The view extract

```
<td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.FocalNeurologicalSigns, 0) 0
</td>
<td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.FocalNeurologicalSigns, 1) 1
</td>
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FocalNeurologicalSigns)
```

The Model extract

```
[Required]
    public int FocalNeurologicalSigns { 
get { return _FocalNeurologicalSigns; } 
set { _FocalNeurologicalSigns = value; } 
}
```

**The validation works fine for other fields that accept string inputs.** In my db, 0 is recorded for the int field FocalNeurologicalSigns even though nothing is selected.

What should i do to make the validation work?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

type `int` is not nullable. Therefore, when nothing is selected for your radio buttons it assigns a default value to the `FocalNeurologicalSigns`, which is 0.

Make it a nullable int and it will work as expected:

```cs
[Required]
public int? FocalNeurologicalSigns
{
    get { return _FocalNeurologicalSigns; }
    set { _FocalNeurologicalSigns = value; }
}
```

Comment: there's a reason why im writing the models as such-for later manipulation. After adding the ?, had to typecast value - (int)value. Still not fixed.

Comment: I wrote it in such way just for simplicity sake. Now it's updated per your request.Recommended [read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx) regarding nullable types.

PS: the _FocalNeurologicalSigns needs to be declared as int? as well.